# Time taking Asp.Net GridView with 2 million Records

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, telerik

I did a task which geting more than 2 millions record from sqlserver and populate them in Asp.net GridView.

The problem is that, query taking more than 2 minutes in getting record while my query is now fully optimized.

when i move from one page to another by pagination it take again same time and hit server.

so i need a solution where its not take time during page movement or get only 50 or 100 record in each request.

Thanks,
Nauman

Comment: Implement paging and use rownum function in your query to return 50-100 records at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use paging in GridView - [check this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)

Also adjust display property like display header with available visible cells to load the grid faster.
Its even better if you bind the grid data using jQuery and not from server side.

[Use this link to get started](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/30/bind-gridview-using-jquery.aspx)

Instead of using GridView you can use repeater or even jQuery templates also with custom paging. that'll be even more fast.

Answer (score 1):

if you are fetching 1000 records and displaying just 50 using pagination, this is really a waste. better to display 50 records each time, this would be much faster. go through the following link:[Custom Paging in ASP.Net GridView using SQL Server Stored Procedure](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx)

Comment: given link is no more available

Answer (score 0):

it's problem on sqlserver...

optimization the data base,separate the database and the table